# Google Login: Trouble accessing the GoogleAuth object

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

I am trying to add Google login to my web app. The gapi.auth2.init() succeeds and when I define GoogleAuth as gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() it doesn't throw an error. However, when I try to run GoogleAuth.signIn() it complains that it is not a function. What am I doing wrong?

This is all within a functional React component:

```
let GoogleAuth

const googleSignIn = () => {
    GoogleAuth.signIn()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('signed in')
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('failed to sign in: ')
        console.log(err)
    })
}

window.gapi.load('auth2', () => {
    gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: googleClientId
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('google auth initialized') // This shows in the console
        GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() // This does not throw an error
    }, err => {
        console.log('google auth failed to initialize')
        console.log(err)
    })
})

return <GoogleLoginButton text="Log in with Google" onClick={googleSignIn} />
```

I wait until I see the "google auth initialized" message and then click the button, but it throws the error as described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() returns a promise, not an object (contrary to the docs, thanks Google), so I just had to do this:

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
.then(instance => {
    GoogleAuth = instance
}, err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Now it works!